# Getting separate different value in an array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have this kind of problem that I can't get the same value in an `array` and separate the different value inside an `array`

I have done using for loop but it seems like my logic wasn't correct.

Value of `$supplier_id` is

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 82 
    [1] => 82 
    [2] => 96 
    [3] => 96 
    [4] => 28 
)
```

```
for($x = 0; $x < count($supplier_id); $x++){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($supplier_id); $i++){

            if($supplier_id[$x] == $supplier_id[$i]){
                 $same_supp[$x]['same_supp'] = $supplier_id[$x];
            }else{

            }
         }
}
```

I want to store the values inside the `array` with the same value and separate the different value.

My expected output is

```
$same_supp[0] = array(0 => 82, 1 => 82);
$same_supp[1] = array(0 => 96, 1 => 96);
```

and separate the different value which is `28` and store it in different variable.

Comment: Can you share what is your expected output? And what type of value in $supplier_id?

Comment: Please share your array `$supplier_id`, and what your expected output is. Your question is very unclear as it currently stands. You're probably better off using a foreach loop over a for-loop though.

Comment: Value of $supplier_id are Array ( [0] => 82 [1] => 82 [2] => 96 [3] => 96 [4] => 28 ). My expected output are $same_supp[0] = Array ( [0] => 82[1] => 82), $same_supp[1] = Array ( [0] => 96[1] => 96) and separate the different value which is 28

Comment: Question details must be edited into the question, not commented under the question.

Comment: You want to ignore/drop `28`?

Comment: @mickmackusa no mate. i want to store it in different variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group them, filter out the single occurrences, and remove the temporary keys.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/39JYB))

```
$array = [82, 82, 96, 96, 28];

foreach ($array as $v) {
    $temp[$v][] = $v;
}

foreach ($temp as $a) {
    if (count($a) != 1) {
        $result[] = $a;
    }
}

var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 82,
    1 => 82,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 96,
    1 => 96,
  ),
)
```

Comment: and where the third value?

Comment: The OP apparently doesn't  want it, see the question.

Comment: **and separate the different value inside an array**, aha

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks bro. But how can i store the third value in different variable?

Comment: Write an else condition to the if.  `else { $singles[] = $a; }`

Answer (score -2):

Since the inner loop ($i) also run on the same iteration as the outer loop ($x), it will not only find the duplicates, but also all of the elements.

You can fix it by skipping the check of the same item (when $i and $x are equal)

```
    for($x = 0; $x < count($supplier_id); $x++){
            for($i = 0; $i < count($supplier_id); $i++){
                 if ($x == $i) continue;
                 ...
                 ...
```